# Hide scrollbar in iframe, while still scrolling

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll

Is there a way to hide a vertical scrollbar in an iFrame, but with still enabling scrolling?

Only thing that hides the scrollbars in HTML5 for me is setting scrolling="no", but this locks the scrolls. All i want to do is hide them.

```
 <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: There is, but it will probably demand JavaScript for a cross-browser experience. This question has some good information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
scrolling="no"
```

and

```
display:none
```

Will stop the iFrame from scrolling. The only other solution is to "hide" the scrollbar via overlapping.

```
<div style="width: 400px; overflow: hidden">
  <iframe src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" width="407"height="480">
</div>
```

Note the 7 pixel difference between the parent div and the iframe, this effectively cuts off a portion of the iframe so that the scrollbar is hidden but you are still able to scroll.

Comment: This seems like the only reasonable solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work

```
<div style='width: 500px; height: 120px; overflow: hidden;'>

    <iframe style='width: 518px; height: 120px;' src=''></iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by putting this in your css file:
`iframe { overflow:hidden; }`

Comment: This does not remove the scrollbar (at least in Chrome)